# How to convert list of characters to columns SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table

```
    A   B   C
1   13  yes Mon, Thu, Sun
2   15  no  Thu, Tue, Fri
3   17  yes Sat, Mon, Wen
```

How can I convert previous table column C string "Mon, Thu, Sun" to:

```
    A   B   Sun Mon Tue Wen Thu Fri Sat
1   13  yes 1   1   0   0   1   0   0
2   15  no  0   0   1   0   1   1   0
3   17  yes 0   1   0   1   0   0   1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to repeat the same expression to test the value for each column,

```
select A, B, 
  case when C like '%Mon%' then 1 else 0 end Mon,
  case when C like '%Tue%' then 1 else 0 end Tue,
  etc
```

Answer (score 1):

full query, with:

1. corrected spelling of Wednesday (`Wed`),
2. assuming your table is called `t`

```sql
SELECT 
    A, 
    B, 
    CASE WHEN INSTR(C, 'Sun') > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END Sun,
    CASE WHEN INSTR(C, 'Mon') > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END Mon,
    CASE WHEN INSTR(C, 'Tue') > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END Tue,
    CASE WHEN INSTR(C, 'Wed') > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END Wed,
    CASE WHEN INSTR(C, 'Thu') > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END Thu,
    CASE WHEN INSTR(C, 'Fri') > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END Fri,
    CASE WHEN INSTR(C, 'Sat') > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END Sat
FROM t
```

returning:

```
A   B   Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat
13  yes 1   1   0   0   1   0   0
15  no  0   0   1   0   1   1   0
17  yes 0   1   0   0   0   0   1
```

Comment: Someone modified my table and then modify it back (you can now look at the correct table).
I tried your code with modifications and your code works too. Thx!